# Merging 3 dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have 3 dataframes with the same ID column. I want to combine them into a single dataframe. I want to combine with inner join logic in SQL. When I try the code below it gives the following result. It correctly joins the two dataframes even though the ID column matches, but makes the last one wrong. How can I fix this? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
dfs = [DF1, DF2, DF3]

df_final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=["ID"], how="outer"), dfs)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5RqF.png)

**SOLVED**: The data type of the ID column in DF1 was int, while the others were str. Before asking the question I had str the ID column in DF1 and got the following result. Then, when I converted all of them to int data type, I got the result I wanted.

Comment: Is it possible to have a sample of your 3 dataframes, please?

Comment: You said you wanted to inner join them but you're doing an outer join.  Do you just need to change to `how='inner'`?

Comment: Looking at your output, my first guess would be that the ID column for one of your dataframes is of a different dtype.  Perhaps two have int columns while the third is strings?

Comment: Try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes I want inner join, I tried how=inner but it returned empty df.

Comment: Yes, one of them has different data type, but I converted all of them to the same data type with the code below. I still get a result like this. DF1["ID"] = DF1["ID"].apply(lambda x: str(x))

Comment: I'm getting a correct output, you should check the dtypes

Comment: The data type of the ID column in DF1 was int, others were str. First I converted DF1 to str and got the result in the question. After your comments I made all of them int and got the result I wanted. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your IDs are not the same dtype:

```
>>> DF1
   ID  A
0  10  1
1  20  2
2  30  3

>>> DF2
   ID  K
0  30  3
1  10  1
2  20  2

>>> DF3
   ID  P
0  20  2
1  30  3
2  10  1
```

Your code:

```
dfs = [DF1, DF2, DF3]

df_final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=["ID"], how="outer"), dfs)
```

The output:

```
>>> df_final
   ID  A  K  P
0  10  1  1  1
1  20  2  2  2
2  30  3  3  3
```

Comment: The data type of the ID column in DF1 was int, others were str. first I converted DF1 to str and got the result in the question. After the comments that followed, I made it all int and got the result I wanted. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`:

```
# use set index to add 'join' key into the index and 
# create a list of dataframes using list comprehension
l = [df.set_index('ID') for df in [df1,df2,df3])

# pd.DataFrame.join accepts a list of dataframes as 'other'
l[0].join(l[1:])
```